# Creating calculated columns in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, pivot

Team,

I have one problem statement to be solved using SQL.

**Scenario** - I need to calculate few columns based on existing columns.

**Logic** - I have a lookup table like below (pasting only sample values for reference)

```
code,metric,value
1,M1,sales
1,M2,cogs
2,M1,netprice
2,M2,discount
```

I have a fact table like below

```
code,M1,M2
1,100,200
2,150,250
```

Now i want to create calculated columns in above fact table based on the lookup table as - In fact table for code =1, 100 value under column M1 should be called sales, 200 value under M2 column should be called cogs etc.

Based on above logic, final table should look like below -

```
code,M1,M2,sales,cogs,netprice,discount
1,100,200,100,200,null,null
2,150,250,null,null,150,250
```

Any help here is appreciated as I am not able to write this logic in SQL.

Comment: I can't see any relation between your Fact table and lookup table. Your looky=up table have M1 as a matric value but how you are deciding that 100 is sale in Fact? Is this hardcoded?

Comment: in fact table, you have code and M1, M2 columns. join fact with lookup on code column and map the M1 and M2 in fact table to corresponding value in lookup table.

Comment: But how you are deciding that in Fact M1-- 100 is "sales" and 150 is "netprice" and same as for M2 too?

Comment: check the lookup table, there is a mapping to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple case statement if you are using M1,M2 value as hardcoded for these columns:

```
Select code,M1,M2,
case when M1=100 then M1 end as sales,
case when M2=200 then M2 end as cogs,
case when M1=150 then M1 end as netprice,
case when M2=250 then M2 end as discount
from fact_table
```

Comment: This is not a scalable solution as i mentioned the values for M1 and M2 are more. Somehow need to join the fact table with the lookup table to make the solution dynamic.